# I'm Backtesting. Why TradingView Strategy Tester Doesn't Have Trades for My Strategy?

Tags: pine-script

I'm Backtesting. Why TradingView Strategy Tester Doesn't Have Trades for My Strategy ?

```
//@version=4
strategy("Simple Long")

Long1 = sma(close,150) > sma(close,200)
Long2 = sma(close,50) > sma(close,150)
Long3 = ema(close,21) > sma(close,50)
Long4 = close > ema(close,21)

OutTrade = strategy.position_size <= 0
TimePeriod = time > timestamp(syminfo.timezone, 2010, 01, 01, 0, 0)

if(Long1 and Long2 and Long3 and Long4 and OutTrade)
    StopLoss = strategy.position_avg_price * 0.95
    TakeProfit = strategy.position_avg_price * 1.2
    strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long, when=OutTrade)
    strategy.exit("Exit", "Long", stop=StopLoss, limit=TakeProfit)
```

The Result Image is attached

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
//@version=4
strategy("Simple Long")

Long1 = sma(close,150) > sma(close,200)
Long2 = sma(close,50) > sma(close,150)
Long3 = ema(close,21) > sma(close,50)
Long4 = close > ema(close,21)

OutTrade = strategy.position_size <= 0
TimePeriod = time > timestamp(syminfo.timezone, 2010, 01, 01, 0, 0)

if(Long1 and Long2 and Long3 and Long4 and OutTrade)
    strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long)

if strategy.position_size != 0
    StopLoss = strategy.position_avg_price * 0.95
    TakeProfit = strategy.position_avg_price * 1.2
    strategy.exit("Exit", "Long", stop=StopLoss, limit=TakeProfit)
```

Comment: Thanks Man ! Your code works and solves my problem.

Comment: I've a further question what if i want a trailing stop ? like -20% from the top ?